# How can I get the final redirect URL when using urllib2.urlopen?

Tags: python, urllib2

I'm using the `urllib2.urlopen` method to open a URL and fetch the markup of a webpage. Some of these sites redirect me using the 301/302 redirects. I would like to know the final URL that I've been redirected to. How can I get this?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Call the `.geturl()` method of the file object returned. Per the [`urllib2` docs](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/urllib2.html):

> `geturl()` — return the URL of the resource retrieved, commonly used to determine if a redirect was followed

Example:

```
import urllib2
response = urllib2.urlopen('http://tinyurl.com/5b2su2')
response.geturl() # 'http://stackoverflow.com/'
```

Comment: how to handle when there are multiple intermediate urls and i want final url ? This does not work for that case.

Answer (score 4):

The return value of `urllib2.urlopen` has a `geturl()` method which should return the actual (i.e. last redirect) url.

Answer (score 1):

e.g.: 
`urllib2.urlopen('ORIGINAL LINK').geturl()`

`urllib2.urlopen(urllib2.Request('ORIGINAL LINK')).geturl()`

Answer (score -1):

You can use `HttpLib2` with `follow_all_redirects = True` and get the `content-location` from the response headers. See [my answer to 'httplib is not getting all the redirect codes'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158895/httplib-is-not-getting-all-the-redirect-codes/11617817#11617817) for an example.